# Async Value Object Creation (DDD)

Tags: domain-driven-design, async, value-object

Suppose that I have a Value Object representing an Image URL of a Cake.

To check that it really is a cake, I make an asynchronous API call to a server that checks whether the image really represents a cake.

Would it be ok to put this kind of validation inside the constructor of the Value Object? After all, I can't identify my CakeImage object without checking first. The other solution would be to use an ImageURL object, and check if it represents a cake when using it, but it seems like a bad solution.

Comment: I recommend you to check this absolutely wonderful talk by Misko Hevery: https://youtu.be/RlfLCWKxHJ0

Comment: Why is checking if an `ImageURL` represents a cake when using it a bad solution? It is in fact the _only_ solution that ensures any sort of integrity within this system. The content of a `url` can change at any time.

Comment: How about a `Future<ImageURL>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're running into the [old argument](https://wiki.c2.com/?ConstructorDoesTheWork) about [how much work to allow a constructor to do](https://daedtech.com/beware-the-bloated-constructor/). I personally like constructors that validate and assign state and nothing more. Why? Here's a good explanation.

> How much work should be done within a constructor? It seems reasonable to do some computations inside a constructor and then encapsulate results. That way, when the results are required by object methods, we’ll have them ready. Sounds like a good approach? No, it’s not. It’s a bad idea for one reason: It prevents composition of objects and makes them un-extensible.
>
> [yegor256.com - ctors must be code free](https://www.yegor256.com/2015/05/07/ctors-must-be-code-free.html)

However, you seem to have found a hole in my policy because I'd be horrified to see a constructor sitting around waiting for a remote server call to respond.

I'd much prefer to see a factory give this remote API calling code somewhere else to live so the `CakeImage` object is testable when the internet is down and is validatable even after the company running the server goes out of business.

I'm leaning towards giving `CakeImage` a constructor that takes the result of this validation, whatever that is, and so can only be built after it's complete.

Of course this means you need a name for the unvalidated pile of data that you're hoping to make into a `CakeImage`. Hmm, `ImageURL`?

Comment: You misunderstood my question: I mean that I have a class representing a CakeImage, not an instance

Comment: I have a CakeImage Value Object supposed to represent a valid cake image. How should I instanciate it ? The CakeImage itself should be immutable

Comment: @HillelSAAL better?

Comment: Thanks much for your answer and your time

Comment: Welcome. Feel free to clean up the comments.

Comment: I read Yegor's post twice and I still have no idea WTF he is talking about.  He turns something simple like parsing a name once, in the constructor, where everything is obvious and you can fail fast, and adds decorators, caching annotations, typical Java overdesign B.S.

Comment: @user949300 feel free to offer a better quote and reference.

Comment: @candied_orange  One excellent programming principle is [Fail Fast](https://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf)

Comment: @user949300 well that’s a whole different principle. I’m familiar with the idea but fail to see how it relates here. Care to enlighten us?

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment of the linked article, I also agree with @user949300 that the example is... well... confused. Maybe if the author considered renaming his interface to `NameThatStartsWithS` or included an example that required `startDate` and `endDate` as construction parameters he could have delineated the difference between domain rules and data rules and expounded upon where different kinds of validation are appropriate. As it stands the article reads as if the author worked backwards from his ridiculous abuse of the decorator pattern to make a point unrelated to the title.

Comment: @king-side-slide can you offer a better quote and reference?

Comment: I think your answer is sound without a quote or reference! I'd actually like to see it either removed altogether or instead leaned upon to provide an example. Maybe: `final CakeImage img = new CakeImage(new ImageURL(new CakeImageAPI(/* ... */)))` would be appropriate. In all seriousness, I don't see how the linked article even contributes to your answer. As I stated above, the conclusion the author draws is _seriously_ begging the question and is only tangentially related to the article's title. That said, it's your answer. I have no skin in this game and will see myself out!

Answer (score 0):

[Fail Fast](https://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf) principle says you should fail as soon as possible for robust debugging.  It is provides quicker feedback to a user if they have messed up.  This goes against the "Constructors should do nothing" principle.

*The good thing about Software Engineering principles is that there are so many to choose from.  :-)*

Imagine that your application asks for a Cake URL.  Version A checks the URL as soon as possible.  Version B waits and does no error checking.  Both then ask for your name, the date you baked the cake, a review of the cake, and walk you through the special offer to receive 3 free issues of "Cake Monthly".  So far, so good.

Finally, Version B does error checking and notices that the URL isn't a cake.

Maybe the user mis-typed, selected the wrong picture, or the code that dealt with that input has a bug and added a leading "http:" when it was already in the URL.  Or maybe it is a cake and the network call is down.

**1) Which would be easier to debug?**
  Version A should have a very clear stack trace pointing to `myUrlHTTPAdder()` as a recent call that perhaps did something wrong.  Version B will have a flaky URL and something about a magazine.

**2) Which will retain more users?**
  I'll let you decide.

That said, doing an async network call in a constructor is a bit much.

**Added**

One approach might be to have a `Boolean isValidatedCakeImage` field, or a method `CakeImage getValidatedCakeImage()`, which returns a Promise or a Future or whatever depending on your language.  (Or maybe just a null and some method of polling or waiting).

At some point in the process your code calls that and takes the async hit.  These methods could be mocked for testing.

A good question is whether the constructor launches the validation, or a later method.  Good arguments for both sides here.  Mainly, I don't think that "constructors shouldn't do nothing" should guide your decision here.  *Lean towards "Fail Fast" as your default*, and back away if that doesn't fit the complexities.

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept of "Fail fast", which is a reason why I like validated value objects. Your last sentence answers half of the question, since you didn't provide an alternative way of doing it

Comment: See edits for some ideas